# Kак найти ячейку содержащую определенное значение и получить данные ячейки находящейся справа от нее?

Tags: python, парсер, excel, анализ-данных

Может кто подсказать как реализовать следующее:

Имеется 500 таблиц Excel в формате XLS, которые содержат различные данные, однако одинаковые по структуре.

Можно ли как-то найти ячейку содержащую определенное значение, и получить данные ячейки находящейся справа от нее? И в идеале записать это значение в отдельный файл.

Пытался использовать бибилиотеку xlrd для поиска ячейки, однако никак не получается сделать поиск по содержимому листа.

Comment: Я бы `pandas.read_excel` попробовал, например

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь Pandas:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd   #  pip install pandas
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)


def find_cell_next_to_val(filename, val, **kwargs):
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, **kwargs)
    rows, cols = np.where(df == val)
    if len(rows) == 0:
        return None
    row, col = rows[0], cols[0]
    if col + 1 > df.shape[1]:
        return None
    return df.iat[row, col+1]
```

---

Тестовый файл:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тесты:

```
In [18]: find_cell_next_to_val(filename, "bbb")
Out[18]: 222

In [19]: find_cell_next_to_val(filename, 3)
Out[19]: 'ccc'

In [20]: find_cell_next_to_val(filename, "3")
```

Pandas автоматически парсит числа как числа, а не как строки, поэтому строка `"3"` не была найдена. При использовании `read_excel()` можно явно указать читать все ячейки как строки:

```
In [21]: find_cell_next_to_val(filename, "3", dtype=str)
Out[21]: 'ccc'

In [22]: find_cell_next_to_val(filename, "3", dtype=str, sheet_name="Sheet1")
Out[22]: 'ccc'
```

Comment: Возвращает ошибку "AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_excel' (most likely due to a circular import)" в чем проблема? Pandas установил. Атрибут изменился?

Comment: а как вы назвали ваш собственный скрипт - случайно не `pandas.py` ?  ;)

Comment: блин, так и назвал D.

Comment: никак не получается... возвращает пустоту, даже когда пробую в тестовом файле

Comment: можете выложить тестовый файл на какой-нибудь файлообменник и значение, которое вы в нем ищете?

Comment: [ссылка](https://yadi.sk/i/pykDUVNkAmc0hg) - файл. В общем я пытаюсь вытащить данные ячеек выделенных желтым цветом в одну таблицу. Решил пойти по такому пути: 1. Найти постоянные строки, например, дата приема заказа 2.Получить расположение ячейки 3.Переместиться левее(правее) на несколько столбцов к ячейкам с  нужными мне данными. Структура всех книг одна, но количество строк в них не одинакова, соответственно ячейки с необходимыми данными перемещаются то вверх, то вниз(из за этого невозможно указать абсолютные координаты ячеек.

Comment: Не знаю важно это или нет, но на всякий случай - каждая книга содержит 3 листа, но интересующие нас данные лишь на одном(наряд-заказ).

Comment: @АА, судя по примеру, искать нужно не соседнюю ячейку справа, а следующую __непустую__ ячейку...

Comment: Да, я так упростить решил просто вопрос. А так расстояние между ячейкой с постоянным значением и ячейкой с переменным значением во всех книгах одинакова.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110891/discussion-between---and-maxu).

Answer (score 2):

Вот вариант решения для [приведенного примера данных](https://yadi.sk/i/pykDUVNkAmc0hg):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd   #  pip install pandas
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)


def find_cell_next_to_val(filename, val, **kwargs):
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, header=None, dtype=str, **kwargs)
    df = df.apply(lambda col: col.str.strip())
    rows, cols = np.where(df == str(val).strip())
    if len(rows) == 0:
        return None
    row, col = rows[0], cols[0]
    if col + 1 > df.shape[1]:
        return None
    col_idx = df.iloc[row, col+1:].first_valid_index()
    try:
        return df.iat[row, col_idx]
    except KeyError:
        return None
```

---

Тесты:

```
In [67]: filename = r"D:\download\пример2020722.xls"

In [68]: find_cell_next_to_val(filename, "№", sheet_name="наряд-заказ")
Out[68]: 'И-3'

In [69]: find_cell_next_to_val(filename, "Гос. №", sheet_name="наряд-заказ")
Out[69]: 'О 327 КК'

In [70]: find_cell_next_to_val(filename, "Дата приема заказа", sheet_name="наряд-заказ")
Out[70]: '09.01.2019 г.'

In [71]: find_cell_next_to_val(filename, "Общая стоимость ремонта с НДС, руб.", sheet_name="наряд-заказ")
Out[71]: '41316.03864'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd   #  pip install pandas
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)


def find_cell_next_to_val(df, val):
    # df = pd.read_excel(filename, header=None, **kwargs)
    # df = df.apply(lambda col: col.str.strip())
    df.loc[:, df.dtypes.eq("object")] = \
        df.loc[:, df.dtypes.eq("object")].apply(lambda col: col.str.strip())
    rows, cols = np.where(df == str(val).strip())
    if len(rows) == 0:
        return None
    row, col = rows[0], cols[0]
    # print(f"row: {row}, col: {col}")
    if col + 1 > df.shape[1]:
        return None
    col_idx = df.iloc[row, col+1:].first_valid_index()
    # print(f"col_idx: {col_idx}")
    try:
        return df.iat[row, col_idx], row, col_idx
    except KeyError:
        return None

def wrap(df, search_val):
    val, row, col = find_cell_next_to_val(df, search_val)
    print(f"Найдено значение [{search_val}: {val}] в ячейке [{row}, {col}]")


df = pd.read_excel(filename, header=None, dtype=str)
wrap(df, "№")
wrap(df, "Гос. №")
wrap(df, "Дата приема заказа")
wrap(df, "Общая стоимость ремонта с НДС, руб.")
```

---

Вывод:

```
Найдено значение [№: И-3] в ячейке [1, 19]
Найдено значение [Гос. №: О 327 КК] в ячейке [8, 25]
Найдено значение [Дата приема заказа: 09.01.2019 г.] в ячейке [1, 30]
Найдено значение [Общая стоимость ремонта с НДС, руб.: 41316.03864] в ячейке [50, 13]
```